# rancher "webhook-service" not found error

Tags: kubernetes, devops, rancher

I have just installed Rancher for test purpose. First I install docker and I install kubectl and helm. Then I install Rancher. When I try to create a new kubernetes cluster, I got this error. I searched about it and it is about the certification error I thought.

> Failed to create fleet-default/aefis-test cluster.x-k8s.io/v1beta1, Kind=Cluster for rke-cluster fleet-default/aefis-test: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "default.cluster.cluster.x-k8s.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://webhook-service.cattle-system.svc:443/mutate-cluster-x-k8s-io-v1beta1-cluster?timeout=10s": service "webhook-service" not found"

I used this command to install Rancher:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped   -p 80:80 -p 443:443   --privileged   rancher/rancher:latest   --no-cacerts"
```

I hope anybody has a good idea and solution for this error? Thanks.

If I want to delete the webhood secret for triggering to create new one, it throws this error:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed this issue with clear setup of Rancher. Now I am able to get the command which is necessary for master and workers. I want to set the master node, but when I apply the command I get this error. 

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html